# Print the last result before 0

Tags: python, printing, skip

I'm using python.
I have this code:

```
def EucAlg(x, y):
    mod = x%y
    print (mod)
    while x % y != 0:
        print (y%(mod))
        mod = y%(mod)
```

I want to print only the last number before 0 when "mod = 0"

```
EucAlg(1112,695)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by last number before 0. Could you provide an example input and expected output?

Comment: You mean the last x or y before mod turns into 0?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need all that code. You can just keep track of `x` and `y` and break when `y` is zero. It makes the idea behind the algorithm much clearer:

```
def EucAlg(x, y):
    while y != 0:
        x, y = y, x % y
    print (x)  # consider returning x rather than printing it


EucAlg(1112,695)
# 139

EucAlg(695,1112)
# 139

EucAlg(10,5)
# 5

EucAlg(13,11)
# 1
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and quality questions some of you have done and answers of course.

@The Grand J. bY 0 I mean, the "mod" becomes 0.

For instance, I'll be clad if you explain what does
---  x, y = y, x % y   --- means?

Comment: @HazloBob this just assigns values. `x` becomes `y` and `y` becomes `x % y`, which is all this versions of Euclid needs to do.